# Two Tables With Same Name Needed - What's wrong with this design?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm working on two website projects at once. However, the two websites will be so interconnected that they are sharing the same database.

For the first site, let's just call it a car site, I created a table called "tag" that holds tags/labels/categories that get assigned to entries, much like the tag system here on SO. Now I need another table to hold tags for a different type of entry, unrelated to the cars. For the sake of example, let's just say I want to tag clothing.

I already have a table called car_tag that joins cars with tags.

Should I be storing tags for the two different types of "products" in the same table? I'm using the nested set model and I think this could get quite confusing and the day something would get corrupted on the entries the website users would be extremely confused.

Any suggestions? Tag1 and Tag2? I think I might need even more tags later on for a different but related project on the same website.

Comment: I don't know, but if I were going to model cars and clothes, I wouldn't be modeling the tags.  If I look at a tag on a t-shirt, it tells me size, price, manufacturer, etc.  To me, these are properties of the shirt, not the properties of the tag.  It just doesn't seem like you're modeling the right thing to me.  Generally, your database model should be based on real-life objects.  Tags just seems like the wrong focus.

Comment: Sorry David, but if you're not joking, you totally missed the point. "Tags" in this case are a way of assigning a given item or entity to more than one "category". For example, in a database of businesses you would assign the business to as many categories as it covers. A hardware store might get assigned Hardware, Lawn & Garden, Household, Industrial, etc. Tags/Labels are the only way to do this effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the tags serve the same semantic purpose, then I don't see an issue with combining them into one table. You should consider adding a TagType/TagTypeId field to explicitly state which type of tag you're storing (cars, unnamed entity).

Just remember that you have the option of splitting them out to different tables if you need to for performance reasons.

Comment: I think I prefer to split them out if only to reduce confusion and chance of corruption, not to mention that the queries are already so complicated that they are pretty much over my head most of the time. :) I guess I'll just have to settle on a naming convention for the tag tables that isn't too confusing. Perhaps I'll violate one of the rules of convention and call them something like "cartags" and "clothingtags" to differentiate them from "car_tag" and "clothing_tag". But just reading that sounds confusing.

Comment: I don't see how there is a danger of the data getting corrupted (intermingled, I assume?), but it is a pretty minor issue either way so you may as well have some peace of mind. You can also consider keeping them in one table, and exposing two views and using those for your queries.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with - they should be perfectly happy to sit in the same table.

In fact, if they represent the same object / concept it would be incorrect to put them in separate tables.

I would also argue that you don't need to 'split' the tags in any way.  If there are `red` cars and `red` clothes, then what would be the harm if they both link to the same `red` tag?  You may someday need to find everything that has a `red` tag, after all.  No harm at all.